# Magento 2 - custom price for product custom options

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to set custom price for product custom options. Basically I have 3 checkboxes as a custom options and their price is 0 at product level.

I wanted to set their price as per customer id.

I was checking this file for changing the price but no clue :- /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/js/price-box.js

```
    updatePrice: function updatePrice(newPrices) {
        var prices = this.cache.displayPrices,
            additionalPrice = {},
            pricesCode = [],
            priceValue, origin, finalPrice;

        this.cache.additionalPriceObject = this.cache.additionalPriceObject || {};

        if (newPrices) {
            $.extend(this.cache.additionalPriceObject, newPrices);
        }

        if (!_.isEmpty(additionalPrice)) {
            pricesCode = _.keys(additionalPrice);
        } else if (!_.isEmpty(prices)) {
            pricesCode = _.keys(prices);
        }

        _.each(this.cache.additionalPriceObject, function (additional) {
            if (additional && !_.isEmpty(additional)) {
                pricesCode = _.keys(additional);
            }
            _.each(pricesCode, function (priceCode) {
                priceValue = additional[priceCode] || {};
                priceValue.amount = +priceValue.amount || 0;
                priceValue.adjustments = priceValue.adjustments || {};

                additionalPrice[priceCode] = additionalPrice[priceCode] || {
                        'amount': 0,
                        'adjustments': {}
                    };
                additionalPrice[priceCode].amount =  0 + (additionalPrice[priceCode].amount || 0) +
                    priceValue.amount;
                _.each(priceValue.adjustments, function (adValue, adCode) {
                    additionalPrice[priceCode].adjustments[adCode] = 0 +
                        (additionalPrice[priceCode].adjustments[adCode] || 0) + adValue;
                });
            });
        });

        if (_.isEmpty(additionalPrice)) {
            this.cache.displayPrices = utils.deepClone(this.options.prices);
        } else {
            _.each(additionalPrice, function (option, priceCode) {
                origin = this.options.prices[priceCode] || {};
                finalPrice = prices[priceCode] || {};
                option.amount = option.amount || 0;
                origin.amount = origin.amount || 0;
                origin.adjustments = origin.adjustments || {};
                finalPrice.adjustments = finalPrice.adjustments || {};

                finalPrice.amount = 0 + origin.amount + option.amount;
                _.each(option.adjustments, function (pa, paCode) {
                    finalPrice.adjustments[paCode] = 0 + (origin.adjustments[paCode] || 0) + pa;
                });
            }, this);
        }

        this.element.trigger('reloadPrice');
    },
```

Comment: do you want to set the price at time of product added to cart?

Comment: No. On product page first. I can manage with cart page and further pages.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya guess i have the same issue. Any answers?